# how to increase the height of select box in ie7 without increasing font-size

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

Height property is working fine with select tag in all browsers perfectly except ie.
I want some solutions which increases the height without increasing the font size.
please help me solving this problem. And I think code is not required for this problem. 
I tried line-height, padding it still doesn't work.

**using ie10 with ie7 mode shows correct output with little difference which is fine but ie8 with ie7 mode doesn't work at all. I used padding, height etc none of them worked. so I am not sure if it will work in native ie7 browser as the emulation is changing in ie10 and ie8**

thanks

Comment: Put a padding top bottom...!

Comment: It is really important that you do not rely on IE's compatibility modes for this kind of thing. What you see in compat mode is highly likely to differ from what a user would see in a real copy of IE7. As you already see, IE7 compat mode looks different between IE8 and IE10. A real copy of IE7 is likely to look different again. Best advice is to avoid compat mode entirely wherever possible.

Comment: The question title says IE7: if this is about emulators instead, then please can you make that very clear, so people like me do not waste time on it.

Emulators are irrelevant to me: I am trying to make a site work for end users, who either have real IE7, or something better. They never, ever use emulators, and if they do, that is not my problem.